# Rename XML elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to change some of the element names in the original XML. I am trying to do this with XSLT, but can't get it to work.

Here is a sample of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<html>
<body>
    <section>Jabber</section>       
            <itemtitle>JabberJabber</itemtitle>
                    <p>Always Jabber Jabber Jabber</p>
            <h3>Emboldened Requests </h3>
                    <p>Somemore Jabber Here</p>
                    <img scr="bigpicture.jpg"></img>
            <poll><p>Which statement best characterizes you?</p></poll>
            <pcredit>Left: Jumpin Jasper/Jumpy Images</pcredit>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<html>
<body>
   <div class="issuehead">Jabber</div>   
   <div class="issuetitle">JabberJabber</div>
      <p>Always Jabber Jabber Jabber</p>
   <h3>Emboldened Requests </h3>
      <p>Somemore Jabber Here</p>
   <img scr="bigpicture.jpg"></img>
   <div class="poll"><p>Which statement best characterizes you?</p></div>
   <div class="pcredit">Left: Jumpin Jasper/Jumpy Images</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the XSLT I did, but I can't get it to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>    
</html>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <div class="issuehead"><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="itemtitle">
    <div class="issuetitle"> <xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="img"></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="poll">
    <div class="poll"><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pcredit">
    <div class="pcredit"><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p"></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h3"></xsl:template>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is an example of badly-formulated question. The title says "Rename XML elements" but there is no clear renaming of elements from the provided source XML document to the wanted result. Also, there seem to be changes in the contents and the rules for these changes are not explained at all. -1 !

Comment: Hmm, right. I don't see how you tagging this "bad-question" improves the situation, so I'll revert the tags.

Answer (score 10):

For anything like this, start with an *identity transform*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node( ) | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node( )"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will just copy every node. But then you add additional templates to do what you need:

```
<xsl:template match="section"> 
  <div class="issuehead">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node( )"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

This pattern should get you what you want.

Comment: Starting simple from a known state is usually the right way to go. From there, the solution can be grown incrementally.

Comment: Could you please explain the selectors to me? It works great, but I don't really understand... Does node() match the element name for instance?

Answer (score 2):

The following template achieves the result you're looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <!-- Copy all elements and attributes from the source to the target -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Transform the given elements to divs with class names matching the source element names -->
    <xsl:template match="itemtitle|poll|pcredit">
        <div class="{local-name(.)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Transform the section element to a div of class 'issuehead' -->
    <xsl:template match="section">
        <div class="issuehead">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you'd like more well formed markup modify the xsl:output tag as follows:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" 
    version="1.0" 
    encoding="UTF-8" 
    indent="yes" 
    omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
/>
```