# How to extract DOM childNodes or rename a element without using iteration?

Tags: php, xml, dom

```
$xml = '<p><a>1</a><b><c>1</c></b></p>';
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$p   = $dom->childNodes->item(0);
echo $dom->saveXML($p);
```

the above will print back

```
<p>
  <a>1</a>
  <b><c>1</c></b>
</p>
```

assume need to replace the `p` node/eleemnt to `new_p`
what is the ideal way except do a loop like below? (below is doable)

```
$fragment = '';
foreach ($p->childNodes as $a)
{
  $fragment .= $dom->saveXML($a);
}

$new_doc = new DomDocument;
$new_doc->loadXML('<new_node/>');
$f = $new_doc->createDocumentFragment();
$f->appendXML($fragment);
$new_doc->documentElement->appendChild($f);
echo $new_doc->saveXML();
```

expected results

```
<new_node><a>1</a><b><c>1</c></b></new_node>
```

Comment: Why are you not interested in loops?

Comment: Where does `<d>` come from your the format that you want? Your intention seems entirely different to the first half of the question: do you want to know how to format the XML to be nicely indented? or, to rename an element? or, both?

Comment: no need nicely indent (what for), rename - **YES** or a method to extract

Comment: With PHP's DOM you can't rename an element directly, you must create a new one and move the child nodes across. Requiring no loop seems an arbitrary decision, can I ask why you don't want to loop? You seem to already know how to get the task done, so why not just do it?

Comment: is not an arbitrary decision, more for optimization purpose...provided there is a method to able to rename element or a method to extract nodes under the element

Comment: @salathe Richard is working on it though: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51389

Comment: I think there is something lost in translation here. I don't really understand where the `d` and `e` elements are coming from. Are you just trying to have prettier printing? Adding more depth to the `c` node? Renaming a node? What are you doing?

Comment: the 2nd example of the xml is the complicated cases, where you need to explicitly do a loop in order the extract the child nodes

Comment: That doesn't answer my question(s). Especially, "What are you doing?" Also, if the second example is of "something else", remove it and replace it with an example of what the expected result is from sample 1.

Comment: So, what is the source XML and what should be the resulting XML document? You haven't defined either of these???

Comment: sorry, my bad, i think I miss a BIG part at the example

Comment: Is there something wrong with just writing the xpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark already pointed out, manipulating XML is easiest with XSLT. And you don't have to write any loops, the thinking is done by the XSLT processor of your choice.

#### A simple how-to with XSLT

Here's how the XSLT might look like (Google for "Identity transform XSLT" for some tutorials).

The basics are simple: this type of XSLT transformation copies everything as-is, unless there's a specific rule (template-match in XSLT) that specifies an exception (in this case for `<p>` elements). Note: it doesn't matter how deep your p-tags are nested, which makes it ideal for transforming XML.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- rename "p" with "new_p", copy everything inside p -->
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <new_p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
         </new_p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Calling XSLT from PHP

This is relatively straightforward, since PHP has a built-in module for XSL. Here's how you can do it ([here's more information](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/xsl.html)):

```
// create an XSLT processor and load the stylesheet as a DOM 
$xproc = new XsltProcessor();
$xslt = new DomDocument;
$xslt->load('yourstylesheet.xslt');    // this contains the code from above
$xproc->importStylesheet($xslt);


// your DOM or the source XML (copied from your question)
$xml = '<p><a>1</a><b><c>1</c></b></p>';
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

// do the transformation
if ($xml_output = $xproc->transformToXML($dom)) {
    echo $xml_output;
} else {
    trigger_error('Oops, XSLT transformation failed!', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Output is as expected (optional indentation can be set with `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>`:

```
<new_p>
    <a>1</a>
    <b><c>1</c></b>
</new_p>
```

As you can see: no loops or iterations ;)

PS: XSLT is a widely adopted and stable standard. You don't have to worry about proper escaping, parsing issues with CDATA sections or entities, because XSLT guarantees the output to be valid XML. This saves a whole lot of headaches as opposed to doing this by hand.

Comment: looks promising, will compiled `--with-xsl` to test (the bounty is expiring while typing this)

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I thought the bounty had already expired ;)

Comment: Huh? I don't understand, I receive the bounty, but I'm not the "accepted answer" nor highest voted? How come?...

Comment: cause the bounty is expiring while i typing the previous comments, it seems promising, so I think I should giving the bount (otherwise, SO will forfeit the 50 points anywhere) and indeed it works after I tested with newly built php compiled with xsl

Answer (score 2):

Is XSLT not perfect for this kind of operation?

[How to rename elements with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737973/rename-xml-elements-using-xslt)

Answer (score -3):

While a loop is an obvious solutions, certain situations might prevent this or make it inapplicable; although I don't know of one. Alternatively it could be achieved by manipulating a string, the input XML string or the output XML from `$new_doc->saveXML()` method, depending on whichever you can use.
I would go with `str_ireplace`, or regular expressions if tags contain attributes, particularly `preg_replace` with `i` modifier flag for case insensitive search. I could provide examples that way if you're interested in this technique.

Comment: You should not use regular expressions with XML, ever. Some reasons: regexes don't know hierarchy (unless they support balancing expressions, which PHP regexes do not support), cannot load and parse named or numeric entities, let alone external doctypes or external parsed entities, have trouble with CDATA sections, cannot deal with namespaces or namespace re-/undeclarations. Use XSLT instead, or XML-DOM traversal, which are made for this. You will just open a can of worms tyring it with regexes.